# How to use information sended by the controller in a JavaScript file using Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot with the Thymeleaf template engine. I have a HTML called clients.html file in the templates folder and a JavaScript file called functions.js in the static folder. I want to send from the controller to the JavaScript file a List.

I have tried using this syntax in the JavaScript file:

```
let listaArticulos = /*[[${numeroArticulos}]]*/ [];
```

But I don't recive anything. I have tried using the script tag in the HTML and it worked, but I want to have the JS code in a separate file and not in a script tag with all my html code.

The controller where I send the information to the JS looks like this:

```
 @GetMapping("/articulos")
    public ModelAndView showHielo(@RequestParam(name = "numcli", required = false) String numcli){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.ARTICULOS);
        mav.addObject("numeroArticulos", searchMovimNumarts("  133"));
        return mav;
    }
```

Where the controller send the searchMovimNumarts() method with the name of "numeroArticulos" the one returns a List.
And the JS file where I want to recive the "numeroArticulos" object looks like this:

```
/*This variable stores data sended by the controller*/
let listaArticulos = /*[[${numeroArticulos}]]*/ [];
console.log(listaArticulos);
```

I want to console log the content of the List using a JS file and no the html
 tag. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymeleaf template engine parses only the template file(html files). So you have to include those variables defined in the controller into the embedded  js code. However  You don't have to put your entire `js` code  in your  `html`. Have only that part of code that refer to those variables in script tag.

```
<script>
let listaArticulos = /*[[${numeroArticulos}]]*/ [];
</script>
```

and refer them in your external `js` after this

```
<script src="/js/externalscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I can use the information stored in the listaArticulos variable in the external js file?

Comment: yes you can. Make sure the order of script tags though.

Comment: Does this answer helped you ?